# Javasound Mixer Not showing any output devices

Tags: java, audio, output, javasound

When I run this code, I get an output of 4 objects, all of which are input. All I want to get is my computer's (Macbook late 2014 w/ OSX 10.9.5) default output.

```
public static void aPlayer(){
    Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (Mixer.Info info : mixInfos){

        System.out.println("Name:  " + info.getName() +  ",     
        Description:  " + info.getDescription());
    }
}
```

this code returns:

```
Name:  Java Sound Audio Engine, Description:  Software mixer and synthesizer
Name:  Built-in Microph, Description:  No details available
Name:  Soundflower (2ch), Description:  No details available
Name:  Soundflower (16ch), Description:  No details available
```

this code, identical to the beginning of [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/nUKya2DvYSo?t=1m15s), worked for the guy making it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me, and I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: I think Java Sound Audio Engine can do output. I've never used Soundflower, but the web page for it says it is for sending AND receiving. Have you actually tried using any of these? Or just letting Java pick a default?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: apologies, and (if it's ok in comments) thanks for editing it for me

Comment: @PhilFreihofner the issue is my system's built-in sound system is missing from the list. Although no, I have not tried soundflower, I'll be to test that now.

Comment: AudioSystem.getMixer(null) returns the system/default Mixer. I don't know enough about Mac OS to know if the "built in" is exposed or not, or if there is another configuration layer in the Mac OS that you need to engage.

Comment: Im not entirely sure if this is correct, but when I do    `System.out.print(AudioSystem.getMixer(null));` it returns `com.sun.media.sound.HeadspaceMixer@f5e0873` .

I'm not entirely sure if I'm right about this, but to me it sounds like it's referencing a class, not an audio channel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try outputting more information about each mixer:

```
for (Mixer.Info info : mixInfos){
    System.out.println("Name:  " + info.getName() +  ",     
    Description:  " + info.getDescription());

    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
    if (mixer != null) {
       Line.Info[] sourceLineInfo = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
       if (sourceLineInfo != null) {
          for (final Line.Info info : sourceLineInfo)
             System.out.println(info.toString());
       }

       Line.Info[] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
       if (targetLineInfo != null) {
         for (final Line.Info info : targetLineInfo)
            System.out.println(info.toString());
       }
   }
}
```

If this shows information about `SourceDataLine` or `Clip` then you can do output on that mixer. If you it has `TargetDataLine` you can do input.